# Уточняющие запятые, авторские, - можно не трогать?

Tags: пунктуация

> А на месте могилы была устроена церковь, в честь Царицы нашей Небесной
>   – Богоматери, на собранные с народа деньги.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно оставить: **А на месте могилы была устроена церковь, в честь Царицы нашей Небесной – БогомАтери, на собранные с народа деньги.**

Обособленный оборот читается **как вставка** (увеличенные паузы, пониженный тон речи), но обособляется запятыми.

На месте тире паузы нет.

Answer (score 2):

Кто не знает, что Богоматерь называют Царицей Небесной? К чему это пояснение через тире? Нигде такой порядок слов "Царица Небесная – Богоматерь" не нашел. Я бы писал через запятую и в другом порядке. А вставку выделить с помощью тире.

А деньги насильно отнимали (с народа) или народ собирал?

Мой варинат:

**А на месте могилы была устроена церковь — в честь Богоматери, Царицы нашей Небесной, – на собранные народом деньги.**

Comment: Ваше предложение мне кажется самым удачным. "Деньги, собранные с народа" — это больше похоже на оброк.

Answer (score 1):

Выделение необходимо, т. к. в противном случае это (когда не обособлено) будет восприниматься названием храма, что в данном случае, очевидно, не так.